# setting up monitoring for integration to external systems from Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, health-monitoring, azure-monitoring

I have created an Azure Web App which contains a method which brings a file from an external system by calling Soap service. How can I sett up a monitoring on this particular method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use application insights to monitor our web application. We can do that with Azure portal or Visual Studio Tool, more details please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net). Following is the snippet from the document.

> Azure Application Insights monitors your live application to help you detect and diagnose performance issues and exceptions. It also helps you discover how your app is used. It works for the Web Apps feature of Azure App Service, as well as apps that are hosted on your own on-premises IIS servers, or on cloud VMs.

We can easily do that with our Azure portal, detail steps are as blow:

Step 1:  Navigate to your Web app in the Azure portal.

Step 2:  Select **Application Insights** in the **Monitoring** blade for the service.

Step 3:  Select **Create new resource** and enter the name.

Step 4:  Select **OK**

I test with Asp.net MVC project on the azure. The following is my detail steps.

Step 1: Add the Application Insights SDK

[image]

Step 2: Update about method and run my app with F5

[image]

Step 3: execute the method

[image]

Step 4: Check operation details from portal.

[image]